# Polyiso foam board

Tags: insulation

I recently obtained several 4”x4x8 sheets of polyiso foam board that is paper kraft faced on both side that was leftover on a job site. Will I have any issues if I insulate the rim joist of my house. I live in zone 6 and the house has vinyl siding over a thin layer of foam underpayment. Thanks for any advice

Comment: Are you insulating from the inside or outside? (I assume inside?) I've installed 1000s of sqft of the same type of polyiso on my house...

Comment: [Only if it's on fire.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/68912/is-it-dangerous-to-use-polyisocyanurate-without-covering-it-with-drywall/68919#68919)

Comment: Planning on installing on the rim joists in the crawl space.